# Vim: only show horizontal scrollbar when line is longer than window width

Tags: vim

With `set guioptions+=b` one can forcefully show a horizontal scrollbar that can be used to fast scroll long lines. But always showing a horizontal scrollbar at the bottom of the window, even when not needed, is a waste of screen estate.

Therefore I wonder if Vim can dynamically show the scrollbar when a line is longer than the window width?

Comment: Do you wonder if there's a built-in option or if this can be scripted?

Comment: @romainl Either way, as long as it can solve my problem.

Comment: Do you really need this? Scrollbar implied using the mouse, which is frowned upon in Vim (for efficiency; there are several commands to move the cursor / view horizontally).

Answer (score 0):

You *could* try using an `autocmd`. The only ones I can think of are `CursorMoved` and `CursorMovedI` ([docs](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#CursorMoved)): you could check the length of the current line or of each line in the file and `set guioptions+=b` accordingly.

To check the lenght of a line/the longest line/all the lines in the file, you can have a look at [this](https://superuser.com/questions/255368/how-to-find-the-line-with-the-maximum-number-of-columns-characters-in-vim-gvim) SuperUser question. Some suggestions are using vim regexes or filtering the content of the buffer through the `wc` Unix tool.

For checking the length of the current line, a vim regex should do just fine and should be fast enough to avoid any kind of delay.
For getting the length of the longest line in the file, `wc` should be the fastest option (I think, I'm not 100% sure).

**Note** that `CursorMoved` and `CursorMovedI` are fired *very* frequently, so you have to carefully watch whatever operation you do in the `autocmd`.